# Spectrum Analyzer with Python?

Tags: python, audio, fmod, spectrum

I want to create a music player with Python which uses OpenGL for visualizing the audio spectrum.
[image]

I already have the 3d engine set up and all I need is to get the spectrum data and feed it to the renderer.
I'd imagine it would be a list of numbers updated each few miliseconds or so.

I've heard you can get that info with FMOD and there's pyfmodex Python wrapper for it, but I can't access the FMOD documentation and the pyfmodex is almost undocumented. Can't find what I need by just browsing the class/function names.
If there's another library which can get that info that will also work.

Comment: As the post clearly says, if there's anything else besides FMOD which can do the job, then that will work for me. Also, I just want to know how to get the spectrum information, whether I use it in a 3d program is irrelevant for answering the question. - for the person who edited the title

Answer (score 4, accepted):

numpy has an FFT function that will compute a fast fourier transform on a block of input data. You can use its output to obtain your spectral information.

Comment: Where can one learn about fourier transforms and what they have to do with this?

Comment: The FFT is a very well known tool in signal processing. Doing a Google search should reveal thousands of pages that discuss it or find and read a signal processing text from your library. For a complete understanding of the theory behind the FFT and its cousin, the discrete fourier transfor, or DFT, you do need to have a bit of mathematical background. To use it, however, just requires that you follow a simple formula.